# Why can't I get my android emulator to connect to my local server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, socket.io, android-emulator

I am developing an app using React Native and made my server with node.js. For websocket connections I use socket.io

The thing is if I install the app to my android device and my android emulator, only my android device can connect to my local server. They both run the same code. I checked and the emulator has an active internet connection. Weird thing is I have an other app inside the emulator that connects to the same server without any problems using the same connection methods.

Do you guys have any idea why there is a problem like this?

Comment: Very difficult to answer based on the information you have provided. Best guess is to check the `class` in Android that creates and handles the lifecycle of the `websocket` connection written in both apps. Maybe there is a slight difference in it which is causing your issue?

Comment: I've actually checked it before and everything is the same. I don't understand how I am able to make a connection with my physical device but not with the emulator while using the same app.

Comment: Well are you connecting from the app using the computer's IP address? Check this out https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking . Says for an emulator to use `10.0.2.2` which serves as a loopback to `127.0.0.1` as the emulator runs in an environment isolated from your computer using a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Android emulators have a built in IP to use when connecting to something on your local machine.

If the socket is running on localhost, you want to connect to using the IP address 10.0.2.2 in the emulator.